# Car bluetooth Problem

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, youtube, car-integration

my year 2009 Mercedes C class can pair with my iphone 5 no problem at all
the car speaker can receive phone calls and I can talk hands free, also when I am using my iphone in the google map nav mode, the speaker speaks well through bluetooth connnection

the problem is when I listening music or watch videos, the speak doesn't work....

Comment: You may want to use a more descriptive title

Answer (score 2):

A common issue is the output selection in the media apps:

Make sure that on your phone, in the media screen, you have selected the correct output source (Bluetooth - Mercedes name) to play the audio (assuming audio is coming from the phone when it doesn't work)

If no audio comes (make sure volume is up) .. However, the Mercedes model / year may not support music playback.

As @tyson mentioned, inquire with the car manual for Bluetooth settings

Answer (score 1):

There are various Bluetooth profiles available as documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387).  The various profiles enable only certain functions.

It maybe that your car needs to be paired more than once.  The Bluetooth profile that handlers music is likely A2DP, whereas the other functions are likely handled by HFP or HID.

Check the manual for your in car audio system and see if it's paired in all modes.

For example, I have a Toyota, and when setting up s new device there are effectively two pairings, each handles certain audio functions.

Comment: A BT device from 2000 is going to be running Bluetooth 1. I'm not even sure that can do A2DP, which was first introduced in 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the car Bluetooth will bug out/glitch and will not pair correctly with the phone speaker. I have a Toyota and it bugs out very often. I will have to fix the music not working by turning off the engine and turning it on again. Sometimes pairing it again will work also. I am not sure why it does this but maybe try to turn the engine on/off.